# Why thumbs up and thumbs down buttons looks better when facing towards each other when placed next to each other?

Tags: buttons, psychology, perception, rating-system

I'm designing a rating feature for an app with thumbs and thumbs down next to each other. i'm curious why is most examples i'd seen the hands will be facing each other instead of being in the same direction(right hands facing right). Somehow it feels more natural for them to be facing each other. is there any specific reason and logic behind this?

[image]

Comment: Well I think the suggestion that it looks better is very subjective and will depend on who you ask. You should really provide both examples in your question too. I imagine part of the natural feeling of it is that we can imagine two people interacting with each other when they are facing.

Comment: More symmetrical. Us humans like symmetry

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is probably more suited to Graphic Design StackExchange